# Limitations of dynamic typing in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I am planing to use dynamic typing in my application. Is there any technical limitations that i should care about? I could not found it Apple official doc. If possible, please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See blog post [here](http://johnszumski.com/blog/implementing-dynamic-type-on-ios7)

OS: It only works in iOS7+.

UITextField: The placeholder font is not exposed in the public API and doesn't use the value of the font property, therefore you can't adjust its size as the content size changes. This leads to a weird effect where the text adjusts normally but if the field is cleared it jumps back to the original font size when displaying the placeholder. You can most likely fix this by subclassing UITextField and implementing placeholderRectForBounds: and drawPlaceholderInRect: with adaptive fonts yourself, however this is left as an exercise for the reader.

MKAnnotationView: The text in the system-provided callout does not adjust as the content size changes. Unfortunately, fixing this requires you to implement the entire callout yourself.

See [here](https://github.com/jszumski/dynamic-type) sample application

Comment: Can i change device font by code in my application as well?

Comment: No, you can't. iOS doesn't allow this.